# Multiple SSD's not showing up in ESXi 4.1

Tags: vmware-esxi, hard-drive, ssd

The previous configuration for my server was

4x 500GB Drives,
3x 2TB Drives,
1x 480GB SSD

and I replace 3 of the 500GB with SSD to look like

1x 500GB,
3x 2TB,
4x 480GB SSD.

The previous configuration worked fine. After the upgrade none of the SSD's were showing up as drives. I took out the 3 SSD's I installed and magically the 4th one appeared. It appears that ESXi is only seeing one SSD at a time. Is there something I'm missing here? All SSD's are in Icy Dock containers and the machine is a Dell Poweredge 2900. All help greatly appreciated?

Comment: What did you upgrade from?  Are all of your storage controllers showing up properly in the configuration tab?

Comment: Just a hardware upgrade from 500GB SATA to 480GB SSD. I should have clarified that the SSD's show up in the bios and all storage controllers show up but the SSD's don't show under ESXi.

Comment: Have you initiated a rescan?

Comment: Yes, they don't show up.

Answer (score 3):

If you're having trouble connecting drives in a non-supported "icy dock", my first suggestion would be to troubleshoot with the manufacturer of the dock. Second, if you want something to just work, use components that are on the server's interop matrix. It's there for a reason.